# $http feed showing cannot read property 'protocol'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm at a loss on this. I have checked the forums and can't seem to find a solution.

I'm working on creating an ionic app to pull json feeds into the app and have them process. I have one feed setup, in one angular module, that is pulling some data perfectly fine. But when I try to create this second module, the feed var it errors, but if I hard code the URL in the $http.get it works fine.

This code errors with TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined:

```js
angular.module('mwre.services', [])

.factory('PropertyFeed', function($http) {

  var listings = {
    residential: "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/categories/1?limit=2",
    land: "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/categories/1?limit=2"
  };

  var content = "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/properties/"

  return {
    getPropertiesContent: function(section, successCallback, errorCallback){
      $http.get(listings[section])
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          successCallback(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          errorCallback(status);
        });
    },
    getPropertyItem: function(id, successCallback, errorCallback){
      $http.get(smalldesc + id)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          successCallback(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          errorCallback(status);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

However, making the following change to the $http.get works:

```js
    angular.module('mwre.services', [])

.factory('PropertyFeed', function($http) {

  var listings = {
    residential: "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/categories/1?limit=2",
    land: "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/categories/1?limit=2"
  };

  var content = "http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/properties/"

  return {
    getPropertiesContent: function(section, successCallback, errorCallback){
      $http.get("http://somewebsite/api-access/get/mostwantedrealestate/categories/1?limit=2")
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          successCallback(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          errorCallback(status);
        });
    },
    getPropertyItem: function(id, successCallback, errorCallback){
      $http.get(smalldesc + id)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          successCallback(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          errorCallback(status);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

I can't seem to figure out what I've got wrong in my code.

Here is the controller that is running that feed. It works perfectly fine when the URL is hardcoded.

```js
angular.module('mwre.controllers', [])

.controller('PropertiesCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $log, $ionicPopup, PropertyFeed) {


  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.successGetPropertiesContent = function(data) {
    $scope.maxIntro = 100;
    $scope.items = data.properties;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      $scope.items[i].smalldesc = $scope.items[i].smalldesc.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
      if ($scope.items[i].smalldesc.length > $scope.maxIntro) {
        $scope.items[i].smalldesc = $scope.items[i].smalldesc.substr(0, $scope.maxIntro) + '...';
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.errorGetPropertiesContent = function(status) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
       var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: 'Error reading property category content',
         template: 'Please check your network connection'
       });
       alertPopup.then(function(res) {
         $log.debug('Error reading property category content');
       });
     };
     $scope.showAlert();
  };

  PropertyFeed.getPropertiesContent($stateParams.propertiesId, $scope.successGetPropertiesContent, $scope.errorGetPropertiesContent);
  $scope.goToContent = function(id) {
    $state.go('app.properties', { propertiesId: id });
  };

})

.controller('PropertyCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $log, $ionicPopup, PropertyFeed) {

  $scope.item = null;

  $scope.successGetPropertyItem = function(data) {
    $scope.item = data;
  };

  $scope.errorGetPropertyItem = function(status) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
       var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: 'Error reading property listing',
         template: 'Please check your network connection'
       });
       alertPopup.then(function(res) {
         $log.debug('Error reading property listing');
       });
     };
     $scope.showAlert();
  };

  PropertyFeed.getPropertyItem($stateParams.propertyId, $scope.successGetPropertyItem, $scope.errorGetPropertyItem);

});
```

Comment: where does error say it originates? Have you tried logging `listings[section]` before making request? Sounds like `section` isn't what you think it should be

Comment: How do you call `getPropertiesContent()` ?

Comment: This is what the exact error is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at urlIsSameOrigin (ionic.bundle.js:26684)
    at sendReq (ionic.bundle.js:19158)
    at $get.serverRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18877)
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:23399)
    at ionic.bundle.js:23415
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24678)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:24489)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24783)
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:20918)
    at HTMLBodyElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:12103)

Comment: well that `undefined` is probably pointing back to `listings[section]` which is easy enough to inspect

Comment: Just added the controller to my original post.

Comment: still doesn't tell us what values are being passed to `$stateParams.propertyId` and what `listings[section]` returns. Looks like if you don't validate `$stateParams.propertyId` you will be open to constant errors and since you aren't using promises properly and are using callbacks instead you won't be able to catch those erorrs